# getting Failed to enqueue tests.: Unknown Exception while running test class

Tags: salesforce

While running any test class in developer console I am getting this error

> Failed to enqueue tests.: Unknown Exception.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is you have hit the maximum salesforce limit. You will get this if your using other then Unlimited Edition. You have to wait for 24Hr to get reset.